# Should I use " European Union's " or "European Union"?

Tags: grammar, double-possessives

Here are my constructions:

> 1. As I said, I am present in territory of the European Union's ,
>      therefore, please contact me only via e-mail at [email address].
> 2. As I said, I am present in territory of the European Union,
>      therefore, please contact me only via e-mail at [email address].

So my question is, should I use 'the European Union's' or 'the European Union'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of using preposition 'of' to talk about possessions with \*ANIMATE\* countable nouns?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/what-is-the-use-of-using-preposition-of-to-talk-about-possessions-with-animat). Also [Why say “of x's” instead of “of x”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38278/)

Comment: "I am present in territory of the European Union" is not grammatically correct (or at least, not the usual way of saying it). Making it "...in **the** territory..." would make it correct, but still unusual. "I am [currently] in the EU" would be how I'd expect most native speakers to say it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apostrophe ('s) talks about possession. Looking at your sentence, I don't think you mean that. Check out two sentences to clear whether to use it or not.

> This is the territory of the European Union

And...

> This is ‎‎the European Union's territory

***Broadly,*** when you use *'...of the...'*, it won't take apostrophe. Because you already said that possession.

---

However, there's something called *double genitive/possessive*, that uses *'of...'s'* constructions. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20genitive) describes it.

> a syntactic construction in English in which possession is marked both by the preposition of and a noun or pronoun in the possessive case (as in “A friend of Bob's is a friend of mine”) —called also double possessive.

[But again, to stay unambiguous, I'd prefer to avoid this usage].

[Good read here.](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doublegenterm.htm)

Comment: It's called (by some) "double genitive". [Check out](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/double-genitive/info) the tag I've added to *the post of Heniek's*. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle Hey, I think it'll be useful to include this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

1. *(?)That is the book of Peter.*
2. (*)*That is the Peter's book.*
3. *That is Peter's book.*
4. (?)*That is the book of Peter's.*
5. (*)*That is a book of Peter.*
6. (*) *That is a Peter's book.*
7. *That is a book of Peter's.*

We normally use the **'s** structure, rather than **of** when we talk about possessions, relationships and physical characteristic, especially when the  'possessor' noun refers to a person, animal or to a country, organisation or other group of creatures [see  Swan (2005.440), *Practical English Usage*]. That is why sentence 3 is natural and sentences 1 and 5 are not. However when the 'possessor' noun is not a person but one of the other types mentioned, both the **of** and the **'s** constructions are possible: *The President of Russia* and *Russia's President*.

We cannot usually put a possessive between another determiner and a noun. Instead, we use a structure with **of + possessive** (Swan p.443). Sentences 2 and 6 are therefore incorrect English. Sentence 7 is natural.  The definite article defines its noun, and sentence 4 is therefore unnatural, though *That is the book of Peter's that I was talking about* is acceptable, as the definite article defines one of several of Peter's books.

So, *That is the territory of Canada/ the European Union/the United Kingdom* and *That is Canada's/ the European's Union's/The United Kingdom's territory* are possible as is *That is Canadian/European Union/United Kingdom territory*. In that last sentence, 'European Union' and 'United Kingdom' function adjectivally.