# a shopper's paradise into "a paradise for a shopper" or a paradise for shoppers"

Tags: possessives

> People regard Bangkok as a shopper's paradise.

If I change the possessive case"a shopper's paradise",
which of the following is suitable.

> 1. a paradise for shoppers
> 2. a paradise for a shopper

Answer (score 2):

> a shopper's paradise

has the meaning of each and every shopper even though the singular possessive is used instead of the plural

> a shoppers' paradise

Your substitute sentence

> a paradise for shoppers

would be more appropriate and the shopkeepers would probably be happier than with

> a paradise for a shopper

Answer (score 2):

> People regard Bangkok as a shopper's paradise.

The original sentence is perfectly correct, and it doesn't need to be changed. But if I had to modify it, I would opt for an **of**-construction and  use the definite article.

> People regard Bangkok as **the** paradise **of** shoppers.

Using the definite article **the** places greater emphasis on the term *paradise*, and suggests that Bangkok is the *perfect* place for every shopper. As an added bonus, you also avoid using the possessive apostrophe, and listening to discussions about whether the apostrophe should come before or after the -s in *shoppers*.

For further information, see also

[Why "the schoolboy" instead of "a schoolboy" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/why-the-schoolboy-instead-of-a-schoolboy-in-this-sentence)
[How do I know when to use "the" versus "a" versus "∅" as an article on a noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/how-do-i-know-when-to-use-the-versus-a-versus-%E2%88%85-as-an-article-on-a-noun)
[What is the use of using preposition 'of' to talk about possessions with *ANIMATE* countable nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/what-is-the-use-of-using-preposition-of-to-talk-about-possessions-with-animat)